# javascript alert not working mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, alert

I have some javascript alert code that displays an alert if a checkbox is not checked if a user tries to click on confirm button and it works fine on desktop but on mobile view/devices, it doesn't work and I tried adding `touchstart`, `touch`, `touchend` into the javascript next to click but nothing seems to work when testing it on my mobile, my code is below if anyone can help, please.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#confirmcheckout').on('click touchend', function() {
    if ($('#terms-condition').prop('checked') == true) {

    } else {
      alert("To proceed you must accept the terms.")
    }
  });
})
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've tried to use chrome mobile view and it works, could you share more code details?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide a functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo. Thanks!

Comment: @Mingze I am trying it on my mobile and it don't work, it just reloads the page

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that 'click touchend' could be firing twice on mobile.

This might help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#confirmcheckout').on('click touchend', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#terms-condition').prop('checked') == true) {

    } else {
      alert("To proceed you must accept the terms.")
    }
  });
})
```

EDIT: Another possible solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#confirmcheckout').on('touchend click', function(event) {
    if(event.type == 'touchend') {
        $(this).off('click');
    }
    if ($('#terms-condition').prop('checked') == true) {

    } else {
      alert("To proceed you must accept the terms.")
    }
  });
})
```

(if touchend works, remove click)

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but it don't seem to work when I test it on my mobile, it just reloads the page

Comment: Thank you, I tried the other possible solution and don't seem to work on mobile, it's just reloading the page and going back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Think I just solved it with the following code

```
<input id="terms-condition" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" name="terms_condition" value="1" required="required" class="custom-control-input" {!! set_checkbox('terms_condition', '1') !!}>
<button class="checkout-btn btn btn-primary btn block btn-lg" onclick="validate()" data-attach-loading="disabled" data-checkout-control="confirm-checkout" data-request-form="#checkout-form" id="confirmcheckout">Confirm</button>

 function validate() {
if (document.getElementById('terms-condition').checked) {
alert("Thank you for agreeing to the terms");
} else {
alert("To proceed, you must accept the terms.");
}
}
```

It seems to work on both mobile and desktop view